# Submit button in Bootstrap Modal works without input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here's an update to my question. I've now addede the html

```js
// Creating new room
        $("#createRoomBtn").click(function(){
          var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val();
          if (roomName.trim() == "") {
            return;
          } else {
                $("#createRoomName").val("");
                socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
                $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
                $("#send").attr("disabled", false);  
                $("#roomModal").modal('hide');     
          }
        });

        $(".modal-content").keypress(function(e){
          var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val();
          if (roomName.trim() == "") {
            return;
          } else {
              if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#createRoomName").val("");
                socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
                $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
                $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
                $("#roomModal").modal('hide');
              }
          }
        });
```

```html
<!--Modal start-->
<div class="modal fade" id="roomModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createRoomLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="createRoomLabel">Create room</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        You can create a chat room here. Names have to be unique.
         <form class="form-inline" id="createRoomForm"><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  placeholder="Room name" id="createRoomName" required /></form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button data-dismiss="modal" id="createRoomBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Create room</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal end-->
```

I'm trying to disable the submit button in the bootstrap modal, until a user has filled in text. 'Enter' works like that, so I can understand why it doesn't work for the button

client.js

```
$("#createRoomBtn").click(function(){
      var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val();
      if (roomName.trim() == "") {
        return;
      } else {
            $("#createRoomName").val("");
            socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
            $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
            $("#send").attr("disabled", false);  
            $("#roomModal").modal('hide');     
      }
    });

    $(".modal-content").keypress(function(e){
      var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val();
      if (roomName.trim() == "") {
        return;
      } else {
          if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#createRoomName").val("");
            socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
            $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
            $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
            $("#roomModal").modal('hide');
          }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").keyup(function(e){
       var a=$('#name').val().trim();
       if(a!=''){
       $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
       }
       else{
       $('#submit').attr("disabled","true");
       }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" id="submit" disabled="true">
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5825/

Comment: This was actually a better idea than my own

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "required" attribute when defining your form elements.

That would suffice.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="saveForm">
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save Me" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>

<script>
 $("#saveForm").submit(function(){
  alert("submitted");
 });


</script>
```

Comment: Like this? <form class="form-inline" id="createRoomForm"><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  placeholder="Room name" id="createRoomName" required /></form>

Comment: Yes! That should be enough!

Comment: Can you update your question and put yout HTML form code too?

Comment: ok, first of all, you have data-dismiss="modal" that makes the modal automatically close on press. Are you sure the form is sent? Because I don't see any reason for it other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire js logic should look like this

```
$('formSelecter').submit( function() {
  var inputField = $('inputSelector').val();
  if ( inputField.trim() === '' ) {
    return false; // this is what prevents the form from submission
 }
});
```

Another way to prevent from submission is to add `required` property to the input field.
Like this

```
<input name="name" required/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input. I got it to work now. I ended up using this code when the modal shows: `$("#createRoomBtn").attr("disabled", true);`

and then this as soon as the user has hit a key`$("#createRoomBtn").attr("disabled", false);`